# How do I implement a controller servlet (MVC Pattern) in an existing JEE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, model-view-controller

I have an existing Java application and currently UI (jsp layer) maps all calls to individual servlet directly.  Instead I want the calls to go through an servlet controller (mvc pattern), how do I refactor and implement the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MVC is about separation of concerns during generating output, not about links in jsp. Try to be more verbose about your current approach and show some source code.

Answer (score 0):

I got 2 idear, you can consider one of them:

- config your servlet in web.xml with path, then in jsp use ajax to
  send request,
- Introduce springMVC might be a good choise, if you want
  MVC pattern.
  Move your servlet logic into springMVC action methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mvc frameworks like Struts(1.2 or 2) or Spring MVC which are built in frameworks for MVC pattern.

In these frameworks you can configure your controller mapping through xml or annotation and requests will go through internal controller like DispatcherServlet which will pass the control to mapped custom controller classes.